# Nested loop not iterating properly

Tags: java, loops, logic, nested-loops

I have this piece of Code in which there are two loops 'i' and 'j'.

'j' is the inner loop variable and it supposed to run 999 to 100 on single run of outer loop.

but it runs randomly like,
suppose i=999

```
j=912
j=911
j=910
j=909
j=908
j=907
j=906
```

Then suddenly inner loop quits, decrements by 1 from outer loop and makes `i=998`

then start 'j' loop

```
j=908
j=907
j=906
j=905
j=906
j=905
j=904
j=903
j=902
```

then quits inner loop ................

```
    int product=0;
    mainloop:
    for(int i=999;i>99;i--){
        for(int j=999;j>99;j--){
            boolean flag= doSomething(i*j);
            if(flag){
                product=i*j;
                System.out.println("Digits are: "+i+" and "+j);
                break mainloop;
            }
        }
    }

 public  boolean doSomething(int product){
        String original= Integer.toString(product),reverse="";
        int length = original.length();
        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
        return (original.equals(reverse));
            
        
    }
```

why is it happening? why inner loop doesnot complete cycle from 999 to 100?

**EDIT:** To clear, 'flag' will be true only if j=913 and i=993 , this is the main issue that loop doesn't break at this point because 'j' never comes to 913 but it randomly generates number.Moreover 'break' will break the mainloop not only the inner loop.

Comment: look at the code in doSomething. that should clear it up

Comment: You are explicitly breaking out of it and back to the main loop at the end of the `if`...

Comment: Can you show the code of `doSomething`?

Answer (score 3):

You have a condition in the inner loop - `if(flag)` - which, if true, breaks from that loop. That's the reason the inner loop doesn't complete. It doesn't run "randomly". Its behavior depends on the result of the `doSomething(i*j)` method call.

Running your code with some additional debug prints and the implementation of `doSomething` you claim to have :

```
  int product=0;
  mainloop:
  for(int i=999;i>99;i--){
    System.out.print ("\n"+i+":");
    for(int j=999;j>99;j--){
      System.out.print (j+",");
      boolean flag= doSomething(i*j);
      if(flag){
        product=i*j;
        System.out.println("\nDigits are: "+i+" and "+j);
        break mainloop;
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean doSomething(int k)
  {
      return k == 913*993;
  }
```

gives the expected output:

```
999:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,...,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,
998:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,...,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,
997:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,...,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,
996:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,...,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,
995:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,...,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,
994:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,...,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,
993:999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988,987,986,985,984,983,982,981,980,979,978,977,976,975,974,973,972,971,970,969,968,967,966,965,964,963,962,961,960,959,958,957,956,955,954,953,952,951,950,949,948,947,946,945,944,943,942,941,940,939,938,937,936,935,934,933,932,931,930,929,928,927,926,925,924,923,922,921,920,919,918,917,916,915,914,913,
Digits are: 993 and 913
```

EDIT, `doSomething` you posted returns true when i==995 and j==583. That's when you break the loop.

Comment: 'flag' will be true only if j=913 and i=993 , this is the main issue that loop doesn't break at this point because j never comes to 913 but it randomly generates number. and 'break' will break the main loop not only the inner loop.

Comment: @HappyDev i==995 comes before i==993, so (i==995,j==583) comes before (i==993,j==913).